# Determine banner ad size on android

Tags: android

I am using `appodeal` to create the banner ads in my android application. I want to reduce the height of my view so as to make space for the banner in bottom. But, I am not able to find any way to get the size of banner ad. How are people dealing with appodeal in their apps then? Did someone find a way to do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Oleg from Appodeal said:

> Hi. Banner can have height 50dp or its height will be determined as
>   follows:
>
> 32: device screen height <= 400
>
> 50: 400 < device screen height <= 720
>
> 90: device screen height > 720

I also noticed that for some 90dp height banners, the image does not take up the entire height and the bottom part of the banner stays transparent. It could be mistaken as a 50dp height banner with a bottom margin.

--- Answering @Anonymous ---

I think you are testing only on small devices. The following screen shots were taken today on a AsusME172 tablet.

Landscape:

[image: banner landscape mode]

Portrait:

[image: banner portrait mode]

The case mentioned when the banner seems to be 50dp but is a 90dp with a transparent part:

[image: banner with a transparent part]

The link to the app on google play in case you want to test yourself. (It's only in portugueese since is a words game, anyway, for sake of testing maybe it could be useful):

[link on google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oigres.roseta)

regards

Comment: @Anonymous well, after this response from appodeal I have implemented this way and seems to be all right. Can you explain more?

Comment: yes..I did allready actualy. I posted below. It's 50dp in portrait...the conditions based on screenHeight are valid when the device is in landscape mode. You didn't specify that.

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed. It's strange, because conflicts with my consideration above, after the appodeal response. I have tested on a tablet wich in portrait mode lead to the described behavior (90dp banner, sometimes with a transparent part, sometimes taking 90dp). Almost sure It was with portrait mode, saddly I have not the tablet at this moment for re-check.

Comment: @Anonymous, I tested again today. My tablet displays appodeal ads with 90dp either in portrait mode or landscape mode. I will update the response with screenshots.

Comment: Well that's what my answer says...That if the device height is >720 in landscape mode the height of the BannerView is 90dp. The fact that it has a transparent part doesn't change the height.

Comment: You commented that my answer was wrong because in portrait mode the banners are aways 50dp. The second screenshot is a banner with 90dp on portrait mode. The 3th banner is only for illustrate the entire post

Comment: I see...if that's true then I stand corrected. I said it was wrong based on the response I got when I asked the AppoDeal staff the same question which is what I posted at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If understand you correctly - you mean banner ad, it's standard size is 320x50 and u can't change it. Also, I wouldn't recommend using banner ads - it goes on users' nerves. Stick to interstitials or videos, they perform better from all points, people perceive them better. BTW appodeal has a cool live chat with tech guys on their homepage, take a look at it. The easiest way to cope with all issues

Comment: I noticed that banner height in dp changes on different screen sizes. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

All smart banners have  height = 50 dp in PORTRAIT mode.

```
In LANDSCAPE mode:

32 dp : device screen height <= 400
50 dp : 400 < device screen height <= 720
90 dp : device screen height > 720
```